# Terraform: how to set the value of a string on multiple lines but the result is one line

Tags: terraform

For readability purpose, I want to set the value of a string on multiple lines but the result would show as a one ligne. I tried to contact using `+` but it does not work.
By the way, one of the lines (a part of the string) is resolved at apply time.

example:

```
output "variable" {
    value = "First part "
          + ", then second part "
          + " and final part."
}
```

and the output.variable will show `"First part, then second part  and final part."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/join.html) function:

```
output "variable" {
    value = join("", ["First part ",
          ", then second part ",
          " and final part."])
}
```

Comment: Thx @Mark! exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you try to concatenate adding a \n character at the end of every variable forming the string? Something like:

```
output “variable” {
    value = “${var}\n${var2}\n”
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Antonio  for your help but my requirement is the opposite, I want one liner result. So I edited my question.